# How to line wrap a long boolean expression with parentheses in java

Tags: java, coding-style, indentation, line-breaks, code-readability

How to wrap this expression in java for more readability with the constraint that the sub expression  `(shouldSendSomething(x) && loooongFunctionName1(x) && looooongFunctionName2(x))` inside the paranthesis is too long to fit in a single line ?

```
!(loooongFunctionName0(x) && loooongFunctionName1(x) && looooongFunctionName2(x)) && looooongFunctionName3(x) && looooongFunctionName4(x) && looooongFunctionName5(x)
```

Comment: "too long to fit in a single line" what do you mean? There is no limit on the line's lenght in java

Comment: I think he means that he has to scroll to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe having each condition on a new line?

```
if (!(loooongFunctionName0(x) 
                && loooongFunctionName1(x) 
                && looooongFunctionName2(x)) 
                && looooongFunctionName3(x) 
                && looooongFunctionName4(x) 
                && looooongFunctionName5(x)) {
            
        }
```

Later Edit: If you have soo many conditions, it usually means that there is a design problem somewhere and maybe some refactoring is needed.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I would suggest to create some helper methods. Wrap some of the conditions into a single method which will simplify the `if` condition.

```
function foo() {
  return bar && baz && qux;
}
```

And use it in your `if` condition like:

```
if (foo()) { ... }
```

or

```
if (!foo()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to assign the results to a meaningful & short (when possible) variable and then use it inside the if clause

```
boolean name0 = loooongFunctionName0(x);
boolean name1 = loooongFunctionName1(x);
boolean name2 = loooongFunctionName2(x);
boolean name3 = loooongFunctionName3(x);
boolean name4 = loooongFunctionName4(x);
boolean name5 = loooongFunctionName5(x);

if (!(name1 && name2 && name3 && name4 && name5)) {
   // something
}
```

Comment: if the expression may still be too long for the `if`-statement, then another variable `boolean name6 = !(name1 && name2 && name3 && name4 && name5);` could be introduced. shortening the `if` even more

Answer (score 1):

According to coding standards in terms of java, max characters in one line can be 80. So here you can wrap it this way:

```
!(loooongFunctionName0(x) 
    && loooongFunctionName1(x) 
    && looooongFunctionName2(x))
&& looooongFunctionName3(x) 
&& looooongFunctionName4(x) 
&& looooongFunctionName5(x)
```

Comment: Is it okay if the indentation is different for `loooongFunctionName1(x)` and `loooongFunctionName2(x)` as per java coding standards ?